# Jersey : Error creating a JAXBContext for wadl processing

Tags: java, angular, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have a REST API coded with jersey which need authentication. To authenticate you need to post to this url : http://localhost:8080/login with your credentials in the body.

It works fine when posting from an API tool like paw but I can't get it to work with Angular 5, I always get this error in the browser console :

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

And this the the server console :

```
WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-11] 
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings 
have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error creating a JAXBContext for 
wadl processing.
```

[Complete Stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/FtL4KAcc)

Here's my config

Resource :

```
@POST
@Path("login")
public Response getSession (Login login, @Context HttpServletRequest req) {

    System.out.println(login.getUsername());
    System.out.println(login.getPassword());

    LDAP ldap = new LDAP();

    String role = "none";

    try {
        if (ldap.auth(login.getUsername(), login.getPassword())) {
            role = ldap.getRole(login.getUsername());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.error(e);

        throw new NotAuthorizedException(e.getMessage(), Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);

    }


    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("user", login.getUsername());
    session.setAttribute("role", role);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity(session.getId())
            .build();

}
```

Pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.26</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Angular code :

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
};

login(username, password) {
    const body = JSON.stringify({'username' : username, 'password' : password});
    return this.http.post(baseURI, body, httpOptions);
}
```

I am using Java SE 9.0.1 and angular 1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

This points to the problem  with CORS.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Server accepts requests only with same origin for security reasons. You could try with setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for server response.


Check this article https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/


Hope this will help you